# как просмотреть время выполнения кода в блокнотах Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

как просмотреть время выполнения кода в блокнотах Jupyter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самое простое - в верху ячейки можно написать:

```
%%time
1 + 1
```

тогда в выводе будет:

```
CPU times: user 3 µs, sys: 0 ns, total: 3 µs
Wall time: 5.96 µs
```

Так же можно установить плагин ExecuteTime в пакете jupyter_contrib_nbextension:

```
pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions
jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
jupyter nbextension enable execute_time/ExecuteTime
```

и еще несколько вариантов на [enSo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32565829/simple-way-to-measure-cell-execution-time-in-ipython-notebook)

Comment: как же мне этого не хватало..